# pandas compare two column from different dataframes and create new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two df's:

df1:

```
       date                         point_id  
0      2010-10-11               121    
1      2010-10-11               433         
2      2010-10-11               6618
```

df2:

```
          id       point_id
0         11       433
1         22       121
2         97       6618
```

Now I want the df to be like:

```
       date                     point_id     cal_id 
0      2010-10-11               121          22
1      2010-10-11               433          11
2      2010-10-11               6618         97
```

What i try:

```
df1['cal_id'] = df1.where(df1['point_id']==df2['point_id']).notna()
```

with error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `merge`

```
df_merged = df1.merge(df2, how="inner", on="point_id")
```

See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for more.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: how will this create the new column `cal_id`?

Comment: the column "id" in `df2` will also appear in the `df_merged`. You can then rename the column, if you want with `df_merged.rename({"id": "cal_id"})`.

Comment: I understand that, "id" and "cal_id" share the same values. Isn't that so?

Comment: what if i only want to merge with the df1 values, would it be left join?